# NHibernate References Dont' save Foreign Key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have 2 classes that reference each other.  It's a weird situation that our CRM needs.

I have an Organization and EmAddress tables and classes.  The Organization inherits from Subscriber, which also has a table.  I think this could be my problem, or the fact that I can't set Inverse on these because there is no "HasMany"...

The order of insert/update is ..
INSERT Email
INSERT Org
UPDATE Email to set Email.Subscriber

Email.Subscriber needs to be "NOT NULL", so this doesn't work. How can I change the order, I can't use Inverse because there is no list.  Just 2 references.

```
    public class Organization : Subscriber
    {
       public override string Class { get { return "Organization"; } }
       EmAddress PrimaryEmailAddress {get;set;}
    }

    public class OrganizationMap : SubclassMap<Organization>
    {        
      public OrganizationMap()
      {
        Table("Organization");
        KeyColumn("Organization");
        References(x => x.PrimaryEmail,"PrimaryEmailAddress").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
      }
    }

    public EmAddressMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, "EmAddress");
        Map(x => x.EmailAddress, "eMailAddress");
        References<Subscriber>(x => x.Subscriber,"Subscriber").LazyLoad().Fetch.Select().Not.Nullable(); 
        /*not.nullable() throw s error.  NHibernate INSERTS email, INSERTS org, UPDATES email. */
   }

   public class EmAddress
   {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual Subscriber Subscriber { get; set; }
   }

     //Implementation
     var session = NHIbernateHelper.GetSession();
     using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
     var org = new Organization();
     org.PrimaryEmail = new EmAddress(){Subscriber = org};
     session.Save(org);
     tx.commit();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post might help: 
http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one

Have only one side use many-to-one (Fluent: "References") and the other side uses one-to-one (Fluent: "HasOne").

Comment: Thyanks, I had seen that post before, but didn't think it applied here.  The CRM that sits on top of this DB has some Business Rules that cause our DB schema to be different than would assume.